# Docker on AWS. ECS or Docker Datacenter

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs

Now Docker is available as Docker Datacenter(Docker AWS) and EC2 Container Service. 
I am planning to host a new application with multiple containers (10+) with high availability (total containers will be 20+). I need to store data with MySQL containers. What approach will be better for this? ECS or Docker Datacenter? Pricing wise, Resource utilization wise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Docker datacenter license costs [$1500 per node per year](https://www.docker.com/pricing), and default AWS installation includes at least [6 nodes (3 UCP and 3 DTR)](https://s3.amazonaws.com/quickstart-reference/docker/latest/doc/docker-datacenter-on-the-aws-cloud.pdf), which means in total $9000/yr only for the software.

I would say that for 20 containers you should use ECS and multiAZ autoscaling which is described here:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/automatic-scaling-with-amazon-ecs/

Comment: Good point. In ECS I hope I don't need to pay for Docker. It seems ECS is a best option.

Comment: There is no additional charge for ECS; you pay only for the AWS resources (EC2 instances, EBS volumes, load balancers, etc) that you use: https://aws.amazon.com/ecs/pricing/.